# How big a vaccum pocket would be required to reduce the weight of an object by one kg?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, buoyancy

Let's say we have a very light-weight and strong material ( [example](https://news.mit.edu/2022/polymer-lightweight-material-2d-0202) ), that could be used to create a vacuum pocket.

In Earth's atmosphere, such a pocket would be able to lift weight because of buoyancy.

My question is, how much volume of vacuum is required to lift 1kg of weight?

The density of air at sea level is about 1.2 kg/m${}^3$. Does that mean about 1/1.2 = 0.83 m${}^3$ vacuum is required to lift 1kg of weight?

Comment: You also have to account for the weight of the enclosing material, which may be low but not zero. The lack of a suitably strong, stiff, and light material is why we don’t have vacuum airships.

Comment: @Chemomechanics That's true; the 1kg might include weight of the enclosing material. I just want to get an approximate idea about the volume required for the required force. And the method of calculating it.

Comment: Your analysis looks fine to me.